# Mutiple @ManyToMany on a single Entity causes Cross Join

Tags: java, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have a User Entity.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "t_login_user")
public class User  extends Auditable<Long> implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "user_id")
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "user_uid")
    private String userUid;

    @Column(name = "user_name")
    private String userName;

    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, optional = false)
    @JoinColumn(name="primary_role_id")
    private Role primaryRole;

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinTable(name = "t_login_user_role_map", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "user_id"), inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "role_id"))
    private List<Role> roles;

}
```

My Role Entity is

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "t_login_role")
public class Role extends Auditable<Long> implements Serializable {


@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
@Column(name="role_id")
private Long roleId;

@Column(name="role_code")
private String roleCode;

@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinTable(name = "t_login_role_priv_map", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "role_id"), inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "priv_id"))
private List<Privilege> privileges;

@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinTable(name = "t_login_role_menu_map", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "role_id"), inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "menu_id"))
private List<Menu> menus;

}
```

My Menu Entity is

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "t_login_menu")
public class Menu extends Auditable<Long> implements Serializable{


    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name="id")
    private Long id;

    @Column(name="menu_text")
    private String menuText;

    @Column(name="menu_icon")
    private String menuIcon;

    @Column(name="menu_url")
    private String menuURL;


}
```

As you can see my Role has multiple Privileges and Multiple Menus. The problem I face is that when I have a code like

```
LoggedinUser liu = (LoggedinUser)authentication.getPrincipal();
List<Menu> menus = liu.getPrimaryRole().getMenus();
```

If I have two privileges say READ_DATA and WRITE_DATA
And three Menus 1. HOME 2.USER 3.PROFILE

my menus variable has a value of  [HOME,HOME,USER, USER, PROFILE, PROFILE] (i.e. 2 privileges * 3 Roles)

I suspect that this is due to my Role entity having more than one @ManyToMany annotations.

I tried to search online and Stackoverflow but no results.
Anybody face this issue? Am i doing something fundamentally wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Okay. I understand where the cross join happens. Since both the ManyToMany are being EAGER loaded, this is where the Cross Join Happens.

If I change to LAZY Load then the issue disappears. Slight performance hit on LAZY load, but thats fine since I do it only once and store the result in the session.